# Querying 2 arrays based on specific indices in Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to pull data from 2 arrays (date and price time series) above a certain date cutoff `oldest` using pymongo.

```
date_price_collection.aggregate([
        { '$match': { 'ticker': ticker } },
        {
            '$project': {
                'dates': { '$gte': ['dates', oldest] },
                #prices to match these dates
            },
        },
    ],
);
```

The way data is organized is there are 2 arrays, one for `dates` and one for `prices` of the same length. How can I pull prices as well that correspond to `dates > oldest`?

Thank you very much for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is first `$filter` the date array, then use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to match the proper prices, like so:

```
const oldest = ...date;

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dates": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$dates",
          as: "date",
          cond: {
            $gte: [
              "$$date",
              oldest
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      dates: 1,
      prices: {
        $slice: [
          "$prices",
          {
            "$multiply": [
              -1,
              {
                $size: "$dates"
              }
            ]
          },
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cemJNIfsaUX)

Comment: Thank you so much @tom-slabbaert !! This worked beautifully. Wanted to ask just one more thing - is there a way to automatically match the size of prices returned, as opposed to hardcoding the size like with the `2` ? I've set it to a large number so that it it always more than number of dates returned - which works, but was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it

Comment: if you want all the prices there's no need to `$slice` as that's what's removing them.  just drop the `project` stage all together in that case.